# Excel select column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, worksheet-function

In excel, if I want to perform a function with the column to the left, how do I go about this?

Comment: What function do you want to perform?  Do you want to create a new column of numbers that uses the "column to the left" or are you trying to condense the entire column to a single number (e.g., a sum or average)?  We'll need a *lot* more information to be able to offer a useful answer.

Comment: I just want to be able to select a different column which is independent of the number, so instead of selecting A1, it selects the cell to the left of the one which is running a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to reference the cell in the column to the left in a worksheet function:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1))
```

there are probably other ways to do it, but I haven't found a good, terse way to self-reference an Excel cell.

To reference the entire column to the left in a worksheet function:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()-1,4),"1","") & ":" &  
   SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN()-1,4),"1",""))
```

Comment: both of those formulas can be shortened to | =ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1) | still long but a bit shorter

Comment: @Xantec, that just gives you the text address like '$A$1', he's looking for the value in that cell.  I'm glad you had me revisit this because I see that the INDEX function isn't needed, so I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in cell H1, and you want to sum column G, type =SUM(G:G).

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a programming question site, I assume you mean in VBA.

The `ActiveCell` is the currently marked cell (or range), `ActiveCell.Column` will give you the column number (leftmost column for a range if memory serves me correctly) that you can use.

Simply subtract one and use it (assuming it's not 1 already, of course). If you want the actual column letter (you don't need it for calculations but may want it anyway), use:

```
Function GetCol (ByVal rng As Range)
    If rng.Column < 27 Then
        GetCol = Chr (64 + rng.Column)
    Else
        GetCol = _
            Chr (64 + (rng.Column - 1) \ 26) + _
            Chr (65 + (rng.Column - 1) Mod 26))
    End If
End Function
```

along with:

```
Dim colStr as String
colStr = GetCol (ActiveCell)
MsgBox (colStr)
```

If this isn't a VBA question, it doesn't really belong here (although I see by one of your comments that you're talking about running a function, so I guess you *did* mean in VBA after all).

Comment: or, if all you want is the address of the cell to the left then this code could be a lot simpler. | GetCol = cells(0,rng.column-1).address | keep in mind that this will return an error if it is run with a cell in column A